# How do I authenticate against Firebase

Tags: actionscript-3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm following [this](https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3/tree/master/database) guide on how to write to my database with an authenticated user. I have set the rules properly and am able to post if all the writes are true just fine. When I pass the oauthToken I get when I follow [this](https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3/tree/master/auth) guide I get "Invalid claim "kid" in auth header". I've seen other questions with this result but I don't think they're doing the exact same things as I am nor are they using the same language.

So how do I authenticate properly? I can get the token and everything else just fine.

Current rule set:

```
{
"rules": {
    "location": {
        "$user_id": {
            ".read": all,
            ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
        }
    }
}
```

}

My code:

```
    private function submitNewData(localId:String, authToken:String):void
    {
        var data:Object = new Object();
        data.location = "w0.0rld";
        data.description = "hello";

        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("https://" + FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID + ".firebaseio.com/location/" + uid + ".json?auth=" + authToken);
        request.data = JSON.stringify(data);
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, entrySent);
        loader.load(request);   
    }

    private function entrySent(event:flash.events.Event):void
    {
        trace(event.currentTarget.data); //Invalid claim 'kid' in auth header
    }
```

Comment: Please read the Refresh Access Token section carefully. The id_token from a login doesn't work for the database, it should be exchanged for an access_token, that one will work for the database and storage.

Comment: How do I exchange it? I'm completely new to firebase so this entire thing (including using what is basically json as a database vs sql) is entirely new to me. Is there some sort of walk through?

Comment: Not exactly a step by step guide, but you can study the following example: https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3/blob/master/examples/SimpleChat.mxml This example allows users to login or register into your app and post in a secure node.

Comment: ..So I get another access token by sending in a refresh token from the same data the guide throws me to get my first oauthToken from? Is that scenario specific to databases or would it also work with storage? ...And what am I saving in my application for returning users, the oauthToken?

Comment: When you login or register, Firebase will give you an id_token, this token is used in the Refresh Token function. Once you call the refreshToken function with your id_token, you will receive an access_token which is also known as the authToken in the guides. This access_token/authToken is used to sign your Database and Storage requests.  Yes, you would want to save the access_token in a permanent file, so you can continuously refresh it. I'm working on an example that saves and refreshes the access_token but it won't be ready until next week. If you wish I can notify you when it is online.

Comment: I have updated this repository: https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/todo-app It lets users login and register an account to manage a private todo list. It will automatically save the user session data (including access_token) and re authenticate on future app launches..

Comment: ? How do I login with facebook using this method if facebook doesn't provide me with a refreshToken? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37674620/do-facebook-has-a-refresh-token-of-oauth/37683233

Comment: Please refer to this example: https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3/blob/master/examples/FederatedLogin.mxml It shows you how to login with Facebook, Twitter and Google in your Firebase project. You need to activate those login methods in your Firebase console, you can see detailed instructions in this link: https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3/tree/master/auth the code is the same for all 3, I recommend to start with the Google login since it is the easiest one to get started with. You are also free to create an Issue in the repository with your questions. :-)

Comment: That puts me back where I started. I didn't phrase my question right. How am I suppose to use database services if I get a refresh token from google and not facebook?

Comment: Nevermind. Didn't follow the guide right when it came to setting up facebook. Doesn't return authtoken unless you have something else set up.

Comment: Actually, I do get this result when I am already registered with Google OR I have already allowed access through the app through facebook. http://pastebin.com/zvwrfwgb

Comment: Ah yes, I am aware of that issue. Unfortunately I don't know how to fix it, the only workaround is to stick to the same login method with the same email address. In this case once you have signed in with Facebook, you keep the refreshToken given to you and continue using it indefinitely. I'll debug this error again in a couple of days to see if I can find a proper fix.

Comment: Appreciate your help! https://github.com/PhantomAppDevelopment/firebase-as3/issues/6 I am posting on your github now so I am not to bother comment readers here. How would I go about searching by chance?